# Selenium - Launch Edge Chromium as different user

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have a requirement to switch from chrome to edge driver chromium

I am having issues trying to launch the browser as a different user. We need to open the browser with different users who have different roles and validate

To manually do this you would right click edge browser > shift and click Microsoft edge > Run as different user

I am using the following NuGet Packages:

```
MicrosoftEdge.SeleniumTools 3.141.2
Selenium.Webdriver 3.141.0
```

Microsoft Edge version

```
91.0.864.54
```

Previously with using chrome and the package Selenium.Chrome.Webdriver i was able to use the following

```
service.StartupDomain = ""
service.StartupUserName = ""
service.StartupPassword = ""
service.StartupLoadUserProfile = true;
```

However with MicrosoftEdge.SeleniumTools 3.141.2 i am unable to find a similar solutions. Does anyone know an equivalent solution?

Current code below

```
EdgeDriverService service = EdgeDriverService.CreateChromiumService(driverpath, msedgedriverExe);

var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;

service. ???
edgeOptions. ???

IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(service, options)
```